# Node js like/dislike with mysql for posts list

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-modules

I have posts list, I'm looking for solution to update like count for each post in list, when count updates.

Answer (score 0):

## suggestion

If you are looking for sql DML then I recommend using

`update YOUR_TABLE set your_like_column = your_like_column + 1 where your_table_id = something`